# Textarea HTML element in Draggable vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, textarea, draggable

The problem is in the realizing the textarea element in draggable component.

So the textarea element contains the text which can be written and deleted, but when I try to choose the text with pointer event like the image below but when I try to do it, dragging function is launching.

[image]

When i try to do it I am launching draggable function so I can not choose necessary text of mine.

It is becoming like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code in your CSS; maybe it will work for you, as I understood your question.

```
.selector {
    user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Not Working even I gave it to textarea element styles did not react!